# Prove that $(\frac{\sin x}{x})^3\geq{\cos x}$ with $x\in [0,\, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

> Let $x$ be a real number satisfying $0\leq{x}\leq{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.
> Prove that $(\frac{\sin x}{x})^3\geq{\cos x}$.

I have a problem I need help. The idea of ​​the proof of this problem is to use Fermat's theorem which is stated as follow

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $R$ whose first derivative satisfies $f'(x)\geq{0}$ with $a\leq{x}\leq{b}$ then $\max_{x\in [a,b]} f (x) =f(a)$ and $\min_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)=f(b)$. In the case of $f'(x)\leq{0}$, the opposite is true. Theorem 2: if $x'$ is an extreme point of $f(x)$ then $f'(x')=0$ specifically if $f(x)$ is a continuous function with second derivative, then if $f''(x')\geq{0}$ then $x'$ is the minimum point and $f''(x')\leq{0}$ then $x'$ is the maximum point.

Comment: A good find @RobertZ, well done. Do you happen to more about the intended meaning of the tag [tag:functional-inequalities]? My first guess is that it is inappropriate here, but I'm not sure. I can, of course, ask in a tagging thread in meta.

Comment: Please, keep your comments short and concise, refrain from giving permissions to comment (=: and subjective descriptions not related to the problem. Cheers! Also, use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/)

Comment: @RobertZ sorry i thinks i have a typo

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks you

Comment: @Invisible Thank you very much, I will learn from the experience for the next time. I will try the method you suggested